# Email attachment sent via smtp to iphone are not visible in iphone native email app

Tags: java, iphone, email, smtp, email-attachments

I have a web service that sends an email with attachments.

the code snippet that sends email is

```
                MimeMultipart content = new MimeMultipart("related");
                msg.setContent(content);
                MimeBodyPart attachment = new MimeBodyPart();
                File file = new File("filename.txt");
                String fileName = "";
                DataSource fds;
                String fullPathFile = mail.getAttachment().get(i);
                String pathArray[] = fullPathFile.split("/");
                fds = new FileDataSource(file);
                attachment.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(fds));
                attachment.setHeader("Content-ID", "<" + id + ">");
                attachment.setFileName(fds.getName());
                content.addBodyPart(attachment);
```

This works fine for every email app. But in the native iPhone email app, I am unable to view the attachment.

[image: As you can see in the image, we can see the attachment symbol. But when I open this email, I fail to find the attachmet]

In the image, we can see the attachment icon but when I open the email, I find no attachments
I also referred the link:
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7491137?start=30&tstart=0

Is there a programing solution for this?

Comment: *This works fine for every email app. But in the native iPhone email app, I am unable to view the attachment.* One of these sentences **must** be `false`.

Comment: Sorry, I meant it works on all email apps except the native iPhone email app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you attache the MimeBodyPart is causing this issue. I had the same problem. Your fix would look like:

```
attachments = new MimeBodyPart(); 
DataSource source = new FileDataSource(dest); 
attachments.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source)); 
attachments.setFileName(source.getName());
mp.addBodyPart(attachments); 
Multipart htmlAndTextMultipart = new MimeMultipart("alternative"); 
MimeBodyPart htmlBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
htmlBodyPart.setContent(body, "text/html; charset=utf-8");
htmlAndTextMultipart.addBodyPart(htmlBodyPart); 
MimeBodyPart htmlAndTextBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart(); 
htmlAndTextBodyPart.setContent(htmlAndTextMultipart); 
mp.addBodyPart(htmlAndTextBodyPart);
```